# How to add Kotlin support to your flutter project?

Tags: kotlin, flutter

Upon reading the `README` file of  [barcode_scan plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/barcode_scan) I encountered the instruction

> This plugin is written in Kotlin. Therefore, you need to add Kotlin
>   support to your project. [See installing the Kotlin plugin.](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-android.html#installing-the-kotlin-plugin)

The link only provides information about creating Kotlin project in Android Studio. How does one add `Kotlin` support for a flutter project? Is it even necessary?

EDIT: Since I already have an existing flutter package, I am looking for ways to add `Kotlin` support to that project

Comment: I can't find the advantages of supporting this in Flutter. Why do you want to add it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You simply have to add a single file in Kotlin format (example under android>main>java>your packagename>test.kt and it will automatically upgrade. Can be an empty file. Add it using android studio. answer reference: https://github.com/mintware-de/flutter_barcode_reader/issues/121

Answer (score 3):

Doing it manually:

Check if you need to do this:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects

Next create a new flutter project for reference and call it myapp.

Next, from myapp/android/build.gradle copy:

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
```

and

```
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
```

Next, from myapp/android/app/build.gradle copy:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
```

and

```
sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
}
```

and

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
```

Next, create the path according to you package path and copy the file myapp/android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/example/myapp/MainActivity.kt

Next, in the file MainActivity.kt replace 'package com.example.myapp' with your package.

Next, if MainActivity.java is an empty class then just delete it under ../android/app/src/main/java/..
but if it is not then you will need change the class and its body to kotlin, copy it and only then delete it.